Graphql SPQR with Spring Boot Starter adding extensions to response
I have a project where I try to map REST api to GraphQL. I have implemented Camel to connect to vide veriaty of microservices via rest, based on graphql query (so basicly my project functions like translator - request comes via graphql and is passed to rest service). I'm using spring-boot, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter (0.0.7) and spring-camel (3.14) for that.
I'm connecting 2 worlds with Service as follows:
@Service
@GraphQLApi
public class GraphQLAPIService
{

    private final ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    public GraphQLAPIService(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate)
    {
        this.producerTemplate = producerTemplate;
    }

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "getInfo")
    public LoginInfo[] getInfo(@GraphQLArgument(name = "name") String name, @GraphQLArgument(name = "nick") String nick) {
        final Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("name", name);
            put("nick", nick);
        }};
        return producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:getInfo",null, headers, ResponseInfo[].class);

    }

Now I'm trying to add to fill "extension" section in root and in "error" part. However, I have no clue how to add info there.
What I've tried so far:

Implement custom GraphQLExecutor like follows:
 public class MyGraphQLExecutor extends HttpExecutor<NativeWebRequest> implements GraphQLMvcExecutor
 {

     protected MyGraphQLExecutor (ContextFactory<NativeWebRequest> contextFactory, DataLoaderRegistryFactory dataLoaderRegistryFactory)
     {
         super(contextFactory, dataLoaderRegistryFactory);
     }

     @Override public Object execute(GraphQL graphQL, ExecutorParams<NativeWebRequest> executorParams)
     {
         Object object = super.execute(graphQL, executorParams);
         return object;
     }
 }



But the "object" which is response is already made so, that I cannot modify it.

Tried to add my own ResolverInterceptor and create custom exceptions, but I couldn't make this work too.

Both thins didn't help me with my 2 issues.
EDIT: Regarding the "motion" to close the question because it is not focus enough - IMHO I'm asking about the same thing: how to modify output, so I can attach some more info than just a data or standard error. I distinguish this in my description because I hoped it will be easier to understand what I want to achieve.
EDIT 2: After reading GraphQL spec about response format, I rephrase my question. I would like just to fill "extensions" in both, root and error sections with additional info.

What exactly did you try with the interceptor? You should be able to return DataFetcherResult either directly, or have an interceptor that wraps the original result. As of graphql-java v21, DataFetcherResult.extensions gives you a way to attach extensions.

Oh, you're also not on the latest SPQR version. You'll want to update so you get graphql-java 21 compatibility. But do also manually verify you're getting the correct version, as Spring might interfere with its own assumed version.
